# Graphs of a functions: $ e^{x^2} , e^{1/x} $

Tags: functions

I don't understand how to plot similar functions without a calculator.
1. $\arctan {1\over x-2} $ 
2. $e^{x^2} , e^{1/x}, e^{2x\over1-x^2} $

Comment: Well, without a calculator it is not straightforward. You should know the general form of $\tan,\arctan, \exp$, etc., and then use this knowledge to plot the general form. You may want to pick 'special' points ($0, \pm 1$, etc.) to 'anchor' the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally look for asymptotes and known values. For example,

1. $\frac{1}{x-2}$ has asymptotes at $x=2$, and $y=0$.
2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(x) = \pi/2 \approx 1.6$
3. $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\arctan(x) = -\pi/2 \approx -1.6$
4. $\arctan(0) = 0$
5. $\arctan(1) = \pi/4 \approx 3/4$.
6. $e^0 = 1$
7. $e^1 \approx 2.7$
8. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{-x} = 0$
9. ...

Extremums (minimums/maximums) and points of inflections could also help when applicable.